# How do you create a new order state for an order status to be assigned to?

Tags: admin, order-status

It's clear how to create a new order status. System > Order Statuses > Create New Status

But how do you create a new state?

"processing", "complete", "new" are examples of the default Magento order state codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml` and find  node. Inside this node, add following.

```
<mystate translate="label">
    <label>My State</label>
    <statuses>
       <mystatus default="1"/>
    </statuses>
    <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
</mystate>
```

> Note : I don't recommend to edit core files. But what you can do is,
>   set this in your own module which is depends on Mage_Sales
>   module.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for. I would agree that it's not smart to edit core files as they'll be overwritten in next Magento upgrade. Assuming copying the file and folder structure into the local folder pool should suffice to do what we want here?

Comment: Rather than that what you can do is if you are writing your own payment module you can set the state by using it's config.xml

Answer (score 8):

you can add **state** by simply add  xml code in your module `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <sales>
      <order>
       <states>
        <order_recieved translate="label">
          <label>Order Recieved</label>
            <statuses>
                <order_recieved default="1"/>
            </statuses>
          <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
        </order_recieved>
      </states>
   </order>
  </sales>
 </global>
```

Comment: default="1"    Is this line is compulsory ?

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can create the status via System > Order Statuses > Create New Status, and then assign the status to a state (System > Order Statuses > Assing Status to State).

Comment: This should be approved answer.

Comment: Why should it be, He wanted a new State not a new Status :\

Comment: Idiot you rasclart read the rass question cuz